# c# index out of bound of array

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

This code gives me an error saying that the index is out of bounds of the array, but if I use `MessageBox.Show()` instead of `ListBox.Items.Add()` the error doesn't occur.

```
string[] arr = new string[gradeListbox.Items.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < gradeListbox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    arr[i] = gradeListbox.Items[i].ToString();
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"[0-9\.]+");
    grade = double.Parse(reg.Match(arr[i].ToString()).Value);
    studentName = Regex.Replace(arr[i], @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
    gradelistbox.Items.Add(grade + studentName);

    // ...
}
```

What is going on? How can I fix it so that it works with a ListBox?

Comment: `gradelistbox.Items.Add = grade + studentName` is still invalid. if it is to be a string that is added, try: `gradelistbox.Items.Add(grade + studentName);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code keeps adding to `gradelistbox.items` thus increasing its count. The size of `arr`, on the other hand, remains the same. Therefore, you get an index out of bounds exception as soon as your loop gets to the original bounds of `gradelistbox.items`.

You can fix this problem by replacing the array `arr` with a container that can be resized dynamically - for example, `List<string>`. This would let you add items to `arr` each time that you add an item to `gradelistbox.items`, keeping their lengths the same.

Comment: is there a way to delete the list you've already processed? For example, after you finished looping the 1st line of list box, delete that line.

Comment: @user3828380 Yes, this is possible, but managing indexes becomes a nightmare. You would be better off creating a separate list on the side, writing it in a loop, and then replacing the original with it after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **AddRange** method for addiing value in list

for more details read this below link

[Why is AddRange faster than using a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836471/why-is-addrange-faster-than-using-a-foreach-loop)

Thanks
-Nimesh