# Should I refactor these nested foreach statements?

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, nested-loops

I have some functions that allow a user to search through multiple directories for files of a certain type, and then just the path of those files is added to a `listbox`. Right now it's done through some nested `foreach` statements. It's going to be retrieving hundreds of thousands of filepaths, so I was curious what other efficient ways there would be to go about this?

Also, I know it sounds dumb to add that many items to a `listbox`. I'm only doing what I was told to do. I have a feeling in the future it will be asked to get rid of, but the filepaths will still have to be stored in a list somewhere.

Note: I'm using the `WindowsAPICodePack` to get a dialogue box that allows multiple directory selection.

```
List<string> selectedDirectories = new List<string>();

/// <summary>
/// Adds the paths of the directories chosen by the user into a list
/// </summary>
public void AddFilesToList()
{
    selectedDirectories.Clear(); //make sure list is empty

    var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
    dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;
    dlg.AddToMostRecentlyUsedList = false;
    dlg.AllowNonFileSystemItems = false;
    dlg.EnsureFileExists = true;
    dlg.EnsurePathExists = true;
    dlg.EnsureReadOnly = false;
    dlg.EnsureValidNames = true;
    dlg.Multiselect = true;
    dlg.ShowPlacesList = true;

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
    {
        selectedDirectories = dlg.FileNames.ToList(); //add paths of selected directories to list
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Populates a listbox with all the filepaths of the selected type of file the user has chosen
/// </summary>
public void PopulateListBox()
{
    foreach (string directoryPath in selectedDirectories) //for each directory in list
    {
        foreach (string ext in (dynamic)ImageCB.SelectedValue) //for each file type selected in dropdown
        {
            foreach (string imagePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories)) //for each file in specified directory w/ specified format(s)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(imagePath); //add file path to listbox
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm using the `WPF` `listbox`, not `winforms`.

Comment: One word... [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)

Comment: .. are you going to be adding "hundreds of thousands of filepaths" to the listbox?

Comment: Yes, as of now that's what the person I'm doing this for wants. There's a chance in the future that they won't be displayed in the listbox, but will still have to be saved in a list somewhere.

Comment: @DavidPine Haven't used much Linq before, I'll read into it. I did read somewhere that underneath the hood it does the same basic operations as a foreach loop though.

Answer (score 1):

One way to begin refactoring this outside of learning Linq would be to use the AddRange method. A good explanation as to its performance advantages over a for loop: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9836512/4846465

There's probably no one answer to this question however.

```
foreach (var directoryPath in selectedDirectories) 
{
    foreach (string ext in (dynamic)ImageCB) 
    {
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but I'm using WPF's listbox which doesn't have an `AddRange` property.

Comment: Perhaps a slight alteration to the above code snippet would be add the results of Directory.GetFiles to a local List<string> then set that List as the ListBoxs.ItemsSource outside the outer most for loop. Good luck, I know little about WPF.

Comment: Hmm yeah that's a good idea. I'm going to do some performance tests on that vs some other ways. The best bet would probably be to make a view model to store the data and bind the `listbox` to that, but unfortunately the rest of this program isn't written that way.

Answer (score -3):

You can refactor it, or you can leave it how it is.

If you refactor it;

Your code will be more readable, understandable and reusable.
You need to write just a couple methods.

And your methods can be usable for another things like your current method.

And works.

If you leave it how it is;

Your code works. But hard to understand and read. Hard to debug in case of bug.
But works.

Comment: Why is the code "hard to understand and read" and "hard to debug"?

Comment: This code is readable enough, but with LINQ, you can do this more efficiently and with less code

Comment: this code contains multiple nested foreach, but if you split foreaches to methods, you can read more easily. and when you debug, you can understand easily what is wrong.