# ComboBox has DataSource set but is not displaying any items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, combobox, datasource

I have a windows form with a `ComboBox DisplayBox`. In my `ViewModel` I now have a Property `BindingList<MyObject> ObjectBindingList` that I want to bind to the `DisplayBox`.

When I load the form, the `DisplayBox` does not show any text.

The property `DataSource` is set and holds a List of `MyObjects` when checking in the debug modus after the data download.
The property items always has a count of zero.

My code works as following:

On startup I set the databindings in the form class to a still empty List ObjectBindingList.

```
displayBox.DataSource = ObjectBindingList;
```

The `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` were set in the ComboBox Properties in the GUI Designer.
Asynchrously the `controller` downloads some data (MyDataObjects) async. Then sets the `BindingList<MyObject> ObjectBindingList` in the ViewModel to the downloaded Objects through adding them.

Comment: [Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019). Set a breakpoint on the line shown above and inspect the collection `ObjectBindingList`. Are there any items in there? Note: if you are using a `BindingSource` obect, then assign the binding list to the `DataSource` of the binding source, not to the combobox directly.

Comment: Is `ObjectBindingList` a `List<MyObject>` or a `BindingList<MyObject>`? You mentioned both. -- Did you reset the bindings, after you added items to the `List(?)`?

Comment: @Jimi It is an BindingList<MyObject> and the binding list is cleared and then filled with the ObjectBindingList.Add( downloadData[i].MyObject ) function.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes No, as the download did not yet happen when I bind the data, the ObjectBindingList is set but has no items ( items.count = 0). I want to set the actual data after the download finished and update the ComboBox accordingly.

Comment: How are adding the data?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes. In my ViewModel  I now assign the downloaded object list as a new BindingList to ObjectBindingList. In my solution I am then updating ComboBox with BindingSource.DataSoure = ObjectBindingList. Is there a better /cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't see all of the relevant code, I can only assume what's happening.

Probably, you don't see the data in the ComboBox, because you are creating a new BindingList when loading the data. But the ComboBox is still attached to the old empty list.

You initialize the data source with an empty list like this:

```cs
// Property
BindingList<MyObject> ObjectBindingList { get; set; }
```

Somewhere else

```cs
// Initializes data source with an empty `BindingList<MyObject>`.
ObjectBindingList = new BindingList<MyObject>();
displayBox.DataSource = ObjectBindingList;
```

Later, you load the data and replace the list:

```cs
ObjectBindingList  = LoadData();
```

Now, you have two lists: the initial empty list assigned to `displayBox.DataSource` and a new filled one assigned to the property `ObjectBindingList`. Note that `displayBox.DataSource` does not have a reference to the property itself, therefore it does not see the new value of the property.

For a `BindingList<T>` to work as intended, you must add the items with

```cs
var records = LoadData();
foreach (var data in records) {
    ObjectBindingList.Add(data);
}
```

I.e., keep the original `BindingList<MyObject>` assigned to the data source.

---

See also: [How can I improve performance of an AddRange method on a custom BindingList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331145/how-can-i-improve-performance-of-an-addrange-method-on-a-custom-bindinglist)

---

To avoid the problem, I would be advisasble to make the property read-only (using C# 9.0's [Target-typed new expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new)).

```cs
BindingList<MyObject> ObjectBindingList { get; } = new();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when trying to update the ComboBox from a different thread than the main forms thread, the update did not reach the control.
I am now using the Invoke Method together with a BindingSource Object in between the Binding List and the control.

```
private void SetBindingSourceDataSource( BindingList<MyObject> myBindingList)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<BindingList<MyObject>>(SetBindingSourceDataSource),  myBindingList);
    }
    else {
        this.BindingSource.DataSource = myBindingList;
    }
}
```

I am expeciall calling the above function on a PropertyChanged event, that I trigger at the end of every call of the download Function.