# How to add a collections of parameters to an SqlCommand before query execution in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I have this code where I want to add a collections of Parameters to an SqlCommand.

```
public void AddParameters(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    if (parameters == null)
        return;

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValue in parameters)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
    }
}
```

I want to make it more efficienty without using a loop because I can have a very large collection of parameters. Is there any way to add the entire collection with a single function?

Comment: The "single function" would have a loop inside it. So in what way is it different?

Comment: Is this loop actually decreasing your performance?

Comment: You are optimizing wrong things. Don't care about micro seconds but code safety. Using `AddWithValue` isn't safe and can cause performance(or other) problems because the type of the parameter must be derived from the value.

Comment: I have another loop before calling this function to build the dictionary of my parameters, so I try to find an optimized function to add parameters in SqlCommand without using another loop.

Comment: Thank you Tim Schmelter, what can I use instad of AddWithValue function? Now in another function I'm using SqlParameter class and I add this to the collection Parameters of SqlCommand

Answer (score 3):

The only way to "optimize" that scenario is to already have a `DbCommand` instance sat around with the correct command-text / type, and the parameters already added, and you simply set the `.Value` of each in turn before executing it against the connection. However, this demands careful synchronization if you are using multiple connections / threads, so would need to be done carefully. Ultimately, **anything** you do here is going to be **nothing** compared to the latency of talking to a database, so: it is very likely that this is simply premature optimization and yak shaving - meaning: you might feel like you've achieved something useful here, but all you're actually doing is spending your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like several things

1. why you need a `public` method to add parameters to a private `SqlCommand` which should not be a field at all but which should be created where you are using it. This is too error-prone.
2. You are optimizing wrong things. Don't care about micro seconds but code safety. Using `AddWithValue` isn't safe and can cause performance(or other) problems because the type of the parameter must be derived from the value

If at all you could use such a method but with little benefit:

```
void AddParameters(params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    if (parameters == null || parameters.Length == 0)
        return;

    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
}
```

The `params` keyword allows to use it in this way:

```
SqlParameter pararmeter = new SqlParameter("@Column", SqlDbType.Int);
pararmeter.Value = 1234;
AddParameters(pararmeter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddRange method to improve the performance slightly:

```
 public void AddParameters(SqlParameter[]  parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
            return;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

    }
```

Comment: @MarcGravell not sure...just saw this question..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836471/why-is-addrange-faster-than-using-a-foreach-loop

Comment: indeed, but there's two problems here; a: the moment we add db latency into the mix, everything else we do will be **irrelevant marginal data**, and b: I would wager that you've actually **added** time here (not removed it), via the `ToArray` - so now it is looping *twice* instead of once, *and* doing a heap alloc / copy.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Corrected.